# Why am I getting unsupported operand type error in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

In Pycharm IDE (Python 3.8) I was trying to create loop to run program for specific period, but received error --> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int' at 4th line

```
  timeframe = 3
    while time(11, 30) <= datetime.now().time() <= time(15, 30):
        timenow = datetime.now()
        check = True if timenow.min / timeframe in list(np.arange(0.0, 60.0)) else False
***Received error message for above line --> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'***
        if check:
            nextscan = timenow + timedelta(minutes=timeframe)
            if not df.empty:
                wb.api.RefreshAll()
                waitsecs = int((nextscan - datetime.now()).seconds)
                print("Wait for {0} seconds".format(waitsecs))
                sleep(waitsecs) if waitsecs > 0 else sleep(0)
            else:
                print("No data received")
                sleep(30)
```

Comment: Well [`datetime.min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.min) actually returns another `datetime` object. You probably want [`datetime.minute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.minute) which returns an int...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. Your suggestion worked :-)

Comment: BTW, I just noticed, it would probably be better to do `0 <= timenow.min/timeframe < 60` then to check for a range. But also it is not necessary, `datetime.minute` returns an int in `range(60)` so why are you double-checking it?

Comment: Because I want to run the program for specific period only. For e.g. Between 11.30 and 15.30 after interval for 3 mins.

Comment: Ok, but again, unless I'm missing something: `datetime.minute` returns an int in `range(60)`, hence dividing it by 3 will still be a number in `range(60)`, so your `check` will always be `True`